# Laravel - Switch Case returns null on relationship object

Tags: php, laravel, switch-statement, relationship

I'm currently working on a project on which I have users, roles and their profiles.

User model has only email and password fields and roles model has name and description fields. They have their belongsToMany relationship on a pivot table.

I have 3 different profiles for each role on separate model classes which are tied to user model with hasOne relationship. I'm trying to assign profile models to users based on their role as each role has different purposes and different fields.

```
public function getUserProfile($roleName)
{
    switch($roleName) {
        case 'callcenter':
            $this->profile = $this->adminProfile();
            break;
        case 'manager':
            $this->profile = $this->adminProfile();
            break;
        case 'admin':
            $this->profile = $this->adminProfile();
            break;
        case 'student':
            $this->profile = $this->studentProfile();
            break;
        case 'staff':
            $this->profile = $this->staffProfile();
            break;
    }
}
```

The function above is called within a for each loop below

```
public function profile()
{
    foreach($this->roles as $role){

        $this->getUserProfile($role->name);

    }

    return $this->profile;
}
```

The profile methods returns hasOne relation object and the profile property is assigned based on switch case matches.

If I query a single user with profile it returns profile fine but when I query all users with profiles and loop them through an if statement to get the ones that the role matches, profiles return null although they are there in the database and attached to users.

```
$users = User::with('profile')->get();

$staff = [];

foreach($users as $user)
{
    if('staff' == $user->getUserRole()->name){
        $staff[] = $user;
    }
}

return $staff;
```

Callcenter, manager and admin roles return with proper profiles but staff and student profiles return null. I'm trying to understand the reason behind this behavior. I would appreciate any explanation to help me get this right.

Comment: Can you `var_dump` or `dd` the `$rolename` above the switch?

Comment: `$this->roles` is an array?

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply Tom $roleName is $role->name within the for each loop of profile function. that part works fine i dded and dumped all those parts. ateoa $this->roles returns belongsToMany relationship object. I solved the problem by lazy eager loading the profiles: $staff[] = $user->load('profile');